# Django point ForeignKey to an existing relationship table

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

I am reasonably new to Django and I want to achieve the following: I have a relationship between two tables, say table B has a ManyToMany reference to table A. Now I want a table called Options which saves options to a specific combination between A & B. How do I achieve this?

Thanks!

Hidde

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) option of the `ManyToMany` Field, and add the information in the relationship itself.

For example

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='RecipePart')

class RecipePart(models.Model)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

# ...
RecipePart(recipe=pizza, ingredient=cheese, amount=9001).save()
```

If the relationship already exists (and you already have data) you will have to update the database schema (and create the model if you used to automatic mapping). [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) can help you do this.